# Running a "Hello World!" ANSI C program on Android?

Tags: android, c

I don't know if that's even possible, but suppose I want to run a Hello World ANSI C program, how do I go about compiling, deploying and running it? Is it even possible?

Here's the example code of the program I have in mind:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    FILE *f = fopen("/storage/sdcard0/download/hello_android.txt", "w");
    if (f) {
        fprintf(f, "File created by an ANSI C program.");
        fclose(f);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, it should create a file as "proof" that it has run successfully.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Compiling**

You just have to known your hardware architecture, find the correct toolchain and cross-compil it with the `static` option. If you don't want to use the `static` option you have to link your binary to `bionic` and not `libc`. It means that you have to compile android from scratch, which will compile `bionic`. Then you could add your `C` files into the "android environement", create a [`Android.mk`](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/ANDROID-MK.html) file and run `mm`.

**2. Deploying**

You have to use `adb` to push your binary to your phone. Something like:

```
adb push mybinary /data/
```

**3. Running**

Launch a shell using `adb shell` and simply run:

```
$ /data/mybinary
```

*NOTE: To do step 2 and 3 your phone **must** be rooted*

Comment: I want to run it on my own phone (Sony Xperia S). I think targeting ARMv5 or ARMv7 will both work. As for step 2 and 3, I thought adb can be used with the *Developer Options->Enable USB debugging*, when the phone is connected through a USB cable, even for a non-rooted phone?

Comment: @sashoalm With non-rooted phone you can run `adb shell` but I doubt about `adb push`

Comment: This is full of mistakes.  You **do not** need to build android from source to get a working build environment - although that's not the purpose of the ndk, it provides one.  Second, you **do not** need to be root to install and run an executable - granted, there are relatively few places where you can store an executable, but the private directory of a cooperating app is one - the app will need to grant public access.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Ok, I doesn't known about the ndk. I always get android source with `repo` and build entirely (I'm not an app guy). Then, I always works with rooted developpement phones, so I'm not completly aware about regular user rights. Anyway, if you disagree with my point of view I invite you to post another answer.

Comment: The question doesn't need answers, as it's a duplicate of at least one existing question here.

Comment: @jml I found a way how to run a native binary without rooting - http://kevinboone.net/android_native.html